# swift json deserialization is wrong

Tags: json, swift

Using postman i verify the json response (list of these `Room` objects)

```
{
        "id": "506e9a1d-cded-4853-a9df-7f8a57d6550d",
        "name": "TeleTwo",
        "shortName": "2",
        "displayName": "2",
        "inService": true,
        "managed": true,
        "capacity": 2,
        "schedulingOption": "VC Scheduling",
        "location": {
            "id": "50b07258-2668-416e-aef4-a8a48e9e7389",
            "name": "Telepresence Test",
            "shortName": "Telepresence Test",
            "displayName": "Telepresence Test",
            "city": "Nash",
            "country": "United States",
            "account": {
                "id": "509788c6-197f-40f1-a7f7-274a23af9062",
                "name": "Development",
                "shortName": "Dev",
                "displayName": "Dev",
                "active": true,
                "exchangeEnabled": false,
                "tmsEnabled": false,
                "commProxyEnabled": true,
                "services": [
                    "Premier",
                    "VMR_Pool_Static",
                    "VMR"
                ],
                "logo": "/provisioning/image/2472"
            },
            "latitude": 45.786368,
            "longitude": -78.505822,
            "active": false,
            "summary": null
        },
        "summary": {
            "totalDevices": 2
        },
        "vip": false
    }
```

I used this json (full list, the above is shortened) on the site json4swift.com to build my dto objects and placed them in my project

Once again shortening for length if requested i can add more (updated it to include all since it was part of the problem):

Room.swift

```
struct Room : Codable {
    let id : String?
    let name : String?
    let shortName : String?
    let displayName : String?
    let inService : Bool?
    let managed : Bool?
    let capacity : Int?
    let schedulingOption : String?
    let location : Location?
    let summary : RoomSummary?
    let vip : Bool?

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case id = "id"
    case name = "name"
    case shortName = "shortName"
    case displayName = "displayName"
    case inService = "inService"
    case managed = "managed"
    case capacity = "capacity"
    case schedulingOption = "schedulingOption"
    case location
    case summary
    case vip = "vip"
}

init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    id = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .id)
    name = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .name)
    shortName = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .shortName)
    displayName = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .displayName)
    inService = try values.decodeIfPresent(Bool.self, forKey: .inService)
    managed = try values.decodeIfPresent(Bool.self, forKey: .managed)
    capacity = try values.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .capacity)
    schedulingOption = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .schedulingOption)
    location = try Location(from: decoder)
    summary = try RoomSummary(from: decoder)
    vip = try values.decodeIfPresent(Bool.self, forKey: .vip)
}
```

}

Location.swift

```
struct Location : Codable {
    let id : String?
    let name : String?
    let shortName : String?
    let displayName : String?
    let city : String?
    let country : String?
    let account : Account?
    let latitude : Double?
    let longitude : Double?
    let active : Bool?
    let summary : LocationSummary?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {

        case id = "id"
        case name = "name"
        case shortName = "shortName"
        case displayName = "displayName"
        case city = "city"
        case country = "country"
        case account
        case latitude = "latitude"
        case longitude = "longitude"
        case active = "active"
        case summary  
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        id = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .id)
        name = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .name)
        shortName = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .shortName)
        displayName = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .displayName)
        city = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .city)
        country = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .country)
        account = try Account(from: decoder)
        latitude = try values.decodeIfPresent(Double.self, forKey: .latitude)
        longitude = try values.decodeIfPresent(Double.self, forKey: .longitude)
        active = try values.decodeIfPresent(Bool.self, forKey: .active)
        summary = try LocationSummary(from: decoder)
    }

}
```

Account.swift

```
struct Account : Codable {
    let id : String?
    let name : String!
    let shortName : String!
    let displayName : String!
    let active : Bool!
    let exchangeEnabled : Bool!
    let tmsEnabled : Bool!
    let commProxyEnabled : Bool!
    let services : [String]!

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "id"
        case name = "name"
        case shortName = "shortName"
        case displayName = "displayName"
        case active = "active"
        case exchangeEnabled = "exchangeEnabled"
        case tmsEnabled = "tmsEnabled"
        case commProxyEnabled = "commProxyEnabled"
        case services = "services"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        id = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .id)
        name = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .name)
        shortName = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .shortName)
        displayName = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .displayName)
        active = try values.decodeIfPresent(Bool.self, forKey: .active)
        exchangeEnabled = try values.decodeIfPresent(Bool.self, forKey: .exchangeEnabled)
        tmsEnabled = try values.decodeIfPresent(Bool.self, forKey: .tmsEnabled)
        commProxyEnabled = try values.decodeIfPresent(Bool.self, forKey: .commProxyEnabled)
        services = try values.decodeIfPresent([String].self, forKey: .services)
    }
}
```

My problem is that `Room.Location` & `Room.Location.Account` are duplicates of `Room`, see screenshot below.
[image]

why is it deserializing my objects like that?

Comment: Maybe this is Xcode bug. Please try `print(returnedRooms)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've checked your code, with minor corrections, otherwise the code did not work: I used the same json, but corrected `summary` properties types:

```
struct Room : Codable {
    let id : String?
    let name : String?
    let shortName : String?
    let displayName : String?
    let inService : Bool?
    let managed : Bool?
    let capacity : Int?
    let schedulingOption : String?
    let location : Location?
    let summary : Dictionary<String, Int>?
    let vip : Bool?
}

struct Location : Codable {
    let id : String?
    let name : String?
    let shortName : String?
    let displayName : String?
    let city : String?
    let country : String?
    let account : Account?
    let latitude : Double?
    let longitude : Double?
    let active : Bool?
    let summary : String?
}

struct Account : Codable {
    let id : String?
    let name : String!
    let shortName : String!
    let displayName : String!
    let active : Bool!
    let exchangeEnabled : Bool!
    let tmsEnabled : Bool!
    let commProxyEnabled : Bool!
    let services : [String]!
}

do {
    let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
    let object = try jsonDecoder.decode(Room.self, from: data) // Here is Room.self, not [Room].self, due to json root object is dictionary
    print("object: ", object)
} catch {
    print("error: ", error)
}
```

In works well and prints:

> object:  Room(id: Optional("506e9a1d-cded-4853-a9df-7f8a57d6550d"),
>   name: Optional("TeleTwo"), shortName: Optional("2"), displayName:
>   Optional("2"), inService: Optional(true), managed: Optional(true),
>   capacity: Optional(2), schedulingOption: Optional("VC Scheduling"),
>   location: Optional(sss.Location(id:
>   Optional("50b07258-2668-416e-aef4-a8a48e9e7389"), name:
>   Optional("Telepresence Test"), shortName: Optional("Telepresence
>   Test"), displayName: Optional("Telepresence Test"), city:
>   Optional("Nash"), country: Optional("United States"), account:
>   Optional(sss.Account(id:
>   Optional("509788c6-197f-40f1-a7f7-274a23af9062"), name:
>   Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional.some("Development"),
>   shortName:
>   Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional.some("Dev"),
>   displayName:
>   Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional.some("Dev"), active:
>   Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional.some(true),
>   exchangeEnabled:
>   Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional.some(false), tmsEnabled:
>   Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional.some(false),
>   commProxyEnabled:
>   Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional.some(true), services:
>   Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional>.some(["Premier",
>   "VMR_Pool_Static", "VMR"]))), latitude: Optional(45.786368000000003),
>   longitude: Optional(-78.505821999999995), active: Optional(false),
>   summary: nil)), summary: Optional(["totalDevices": 2]), vip:
>   Optional(false))

Seems everything is ok.

Comment: FYI:  I didn't need summary so i just removed it but the problem remained.  what really fixed it was removing (commented out) the other 2 methods that son4swift.com built - enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey AND init(from decoder: Decoder) throws